# Call custom Ethereum fallback function with web3.py

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3py

I'm trying to implement an upgradable function through delegation. Essentially, the fallback function of `contract A` is implemented in such a way that when calling function `F` on `contract A`, the execution is delegated to function `F` (same function signature( on `contract B`.

Callback function looks like this

```
function() external payable {
        address delegate = delegates[msg.sig];
        require(delegate != address(0), "Function does not exist.");
        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
            let result := delegatecall(gas, delegate, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
            let size := returndatasize
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)
            switch result
            case 0 {revert(ptr, size)}
            default {return (ptr, size)}
        }
    }
```

I ran into problem when trying to use web3.py to call function `F` in said `contract A`. I trie a few different things:

```
// Case 1
Contract.functions.F().buildTransaction()
```

^ this caused the web3.py to complain that function F is not in `contract A`'s ABI. So then I thought the fallback function uses `msg.sig` as function signature, so I tried to pass the signature as "data".

```
// Case 2
Contract.fallback.buildTransaction({'data': "0x61455567"})
// 0x61455567 == bytes4(keccak256("updateContract(address,string,string)"))
```

which also didn't work because web3.py says "data" cannot be called when building transaction. Finally, I thought I could pass the `data` field after building the transaction, so I did:

```
// Case 3
txn_hash = Contract.fallback.buildTransaction({'gas': 1000000})
txn_hash['data'] = "0x837b4bd1"
```

This time, web3.py didn't complain but the transaction failed on the blockchain (on Rinkeby testnet).

Any help on how to use web3.py to call a custom fallback function?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `sendTransaction` and then it will go into the fallback function.

```js
web3.eth.sendTransaction({'to': contractAddress, 'from': yourAddress, 'data': "0x61455567"})
```

EDIT:

You can also sign a transaction locally, [reference](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction)

Comment: sendTransaction doesn't seem to work with Infura - the transaction needs to be signed locally